# WooCommerce - conditionally request payment info for free products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So what I need probably has simple solution, but I suck at this, so I need help. My client has two free membership products added to her site (WooCommerce), plus various pay products. What I need is for one free membership product to request credit card info (it is a subscription box style membership) for the future shipments, and the other free membership too not require credit card info. I added this snippet to require the card info for the one membership, but is there a way to make it conditional to only require it for the one free membership and not the other?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_payment', '__return_true' );
```

I'm assuming we need to check the cart for the one free product, then return the credit card form if said product is in the cart, but I'm not sure at all how to write that.

Comment: you can use `WC()->cart` in the hook to read the cart

Comment: Unfortunately, I really know nothing about this stuff, so I have no idea where to even go with that... this project has gone way beyond my designing skillset...